# Cannot read property 'Autocomplete' of undefined while using google-places api

Tags: angular, google-maps, angular6

I want to get LatLng of entered address in textbox. I am using google map api for it. By writing only **new google.maps.places.Autocomplete({})** I am getting **Cannot read property 'places' of undefined** this error.

Below is my code:

```
@ViewChild('addressText') addressText: any;

ngAfterViewInit() {
   this.getPlaceAutocomplete();
}

getPlaceAutocomplete() {
    const autoComplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(this.addressText.nativeElement, {
      types: this.addressText.nativeElement.value
    })
    // google.maps.event.addListener(autoComplete, 'place_changed', () => {
    //   const place = autoComplete.getPlace();

    //   console.log('places... ', place);
    // })
  }
```

**html file:**

```
<input matInput placeholder="Locations" class="input" formControlName="text" #addressText>
```

Please help me out.

Comment: did you install and import google maps? like for install `npm install --save @types/googlemaps` and to import `import { } from '@types/googlemaps';`

Comment: Yes @Kenny, I did

Answer (score 1):

I Faced The Same Issue And I was forgot to add &libraries=places after my key
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places"

Answer (score 0):

The error is because of 'autocomplete' object is not created.

- You need to defined a id for'input' tag.
- Just giving you a basic example.

**HTML:**

```
<input matInput placeholder="Locations" class="input" formControlName="text" id="addressText">
```

**JS:**

```
autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
  document.getElementById('addressText'), {types: ['geocode']});
```

For further details please go the through docs [google api autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform)

Comment: @JaynaTanawala have you followed the above steps?

Comment: @JaynaTanawala Can you please provide a stackbliz or plunkr sample for this issue so that can check at my end as well.